# UberJar doesn't work: Intellij Maven java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with Jackson YAML

Tags: java, maven, jackson

I'm trying to run a very simple program, which requires a class in runtime:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        YAMLFactory yf =  new YAMLFactory();
    }
}
```

It's getting compiled, but I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/yaml/YAMLFactory
    at App.main(App.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory
```

running the jar.

I use both `maven-assembly-plugin` and `maven-shade-plugin` to include dependencies to the jar, both none of them are working for me.

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>App</groupId>
    <artifactId>App</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Compile in Java 1.8 -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>App</mainClass>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <transformers>
                                    <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
                                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                        <mainClass>App</mainClass>
                                    </transformer>
                                </transformers>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure your maven assembly plugin like this (you do not need the other plugin).
This will put all the .class files in your jar.

`mvn clean install` to generate your jar and then `java -jar target/yourJar-jar-with-dependencies.jar` to execute.
For more details check http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

I leave you an improved pom file  for maven 3 (**actually the problem was with the pluginManagement tag which is not available on this version of maven**).
You also do not need the maven jar plugin.

Please find both schemas for full details

https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-v3_0_0.xsd

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>App</groupId>
    <artifactId>App</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
    <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>your-jar-1.0</finalName>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                <mainClass>App</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>make-assembly</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Compile in Java 1.8 -->
                <!--<plugin>-->
                    <!--&lt;!&ndash; Build an executable JAR &ndash;&gt;-->
                    <!--<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
                    <!--<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>       -->
                    <!--<version>3.1.0</version>-->
                    <!--<configuration>-->
                        <!--<archive>-->
                            <!--<manifest>-->
                                <!--<mainClass>App</mainClass>-->
                                <!--<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>-->
                            <!--</manifest>-->
                        <!--</archive>-->
                    <!--</configuration>-->
                <!--</plugin>-->
            </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Yep, I use the maven assembly plugin, also tried exactly with your parameters (also getting rid of others, except of `maven-jar-plugin`), but still get the same error. As about dependency, as far as I understand YAMLFactory needs `jackson-dataformat-yaml`, which is in pom.xml

Comment: Ok, you should open your generated jar (can use vim on Linux, 7z on Windows) and check if you have the file com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/yaml/YAMLFactory

Comment: Nope, it's not there. The plugin doesn't pack dependencies to the jar

Comment: Just tested and worked for me, in your target folder you should see a XXx-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: The problem was in extra pluginManagement tag, now it works, thanks!